# Issue with Changing a radio button value based on a users age

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I am trying to develop some JS that will allow a form to change the value of a submitted radio button based on the users age.  Essentially, if the user is 13yo or younger AND selected radio1 value of '100', it should change the '100' to a blank.

Below is the code.  No matter what i do, it seems to always see the user as being over the age of 13.  Any help is appreciated!

```
var ofAge = "N"

function checkAge() {
  var monInput = document.querySelector("#i_date_of_birth_month").value
  var dayInput = document.querySelector("#i_date_of_birth_day").value
  var yearInput = document.querySelector("#i_date_of_birth_year").value
  var dateString = monInput + ", " + dayInput + ", " + yearInput
  var birthDate = new Date(dateString);
  var todayDate = new Date()
  var age = todayDate.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
  var m = birthDate.getMonth() - todayDate.getMonth()
  if (m < 0) {
    age--
  }
  if (age > 13) {
    ofAge = "Y"
  } else if (age == 13) {
      var d = birthDate.getDate() - todayDate.getDate()
      if (d >= 0) {
        ofAge = "Y"
      } else {
        ofAge = "N"
      }
    }
  if (ofAge == "N") {
    document.querySelector("#radio1").value = ""
  } else {
    document.querySelector("#radio1").value = "100"
  }
}

document.getElementById("i_date_of_birth_day").addEventListener("change", checkAge)
document.getElementById("i_date_of_birth_year").addEventListener("change", checkAge)
document.getElementById("i_date_of_birth_month").addEventListener("change", checkAge)
```

Comment: There's no jquery in this code

Comment: Why would you want to use `"N"` or `"Y"` instead of proper booleans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on [@tech2017's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49286446/5463636), you also need to change the way you're processing the date. Instead of commas and spaces, use a hyphen (`-`) in between each field to build the date object.

See the code below for @tech2017's answer modified to correctly build the date. The `console.log()` calls are in there so you can see what's being generated and changed.

```js
var ofAge = "N"

function checkAge() {
  var monInput = document.querySelector("#i_date_of_birth_month").value
  var dayInput = document.querySelector("#i_date_of_birth_day").value
  var yearInput = document.querySelector("#i_date_of_birth_year").value
  var dateString = monInput + "-" + dayInput + "-" + yearInput
  console.log("dateString: " + dateString);
  var birthDate = new Date(dateString);
  console.log("birthDate: " + birthDate);
  var todayDate = new Date()
  var age = todayDate.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
  var m = birthDate.getMonth() - todayDate.getMonth()
  if (m < 0) {
    age--
  }
  age = parseFloat(age);
  if (age > 13) {
    ofAge = "Y"
  } else if (age == 13) {
    var d = birthDate.getDate() - todayDate.getDate()
    if (d >= 0) {
      ofAge = "Y"
    } else {
      ofAge = "N"
    }
  } else {
    ofAge = "N";
  }
  if (ofAge == "N") {
    document.querySelector("#radio1").value = ""
  } else {
    document.querySelector("#radio1").value = "100"
  }
  console.log("radio1 value = " + document.querySelector("#radio1").value);
}

document.getElementById("i_date_of_birth_day").addEventListener("change", checkAge)
document.getElementById("i_date_of_birth_year").addEventListener("change", checkAge)
document.getElementById("i_date_of_birth_month").addEventListener("change", checkAge)
```

```html
<input type="text" name="" id="i_date_of_birth_day">
<input type="text" name="" id="i_date_of_birth_month">
<input type="text" name="" id="i_date_of_birth_year">

<input type="radio" name="" id="radio1">
<input type="radio" name="" id="radio2">
```

Comment: and this solved it and made a lot of sense.  appreciate your time!

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `else` statement if age is less than 13.

`} else {
    ofAge = "N";
}`

```js
var ofAge = "N"

function checkAge() {
  var monInput = document.querySelector("#i_date_of_birth_month").value
  var dayInput = document.querySelector("#i_date_of_birth_day").value
  var yearInput = document.querySelector("#i_date_of_birth_year").value
  var dateString = monInput + ", " + dayInput + ", " + yearInput
  var birthDate = new Date(dateString);
  var todayDate = new Date()
  var age = todayDate.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
  var m = birthDate.getMonth() - todayDate.getMonth()
  if (m < 0) {
    age--
  }
  age = parseFloat(age);
  if (age > 13) {
    ofAge = "Y"
  } else if (age == 13) {
    var d = birthDate.getDate() - todayDate.getDate()
    if (d >= 0) {
      ofAge = "Y"
    } else {
      ofAge = "N"
    }
  } else {
    ofAge = "N";
  }
  if (ofAge == "N") {
    document.querySelector("#radio1").value = ""
  } else {
    document.querySelector("#radio1").value = "100"
  }
}

document.getElementById("i_date_of_birth_day").addEventListener("change", checkAge)
document.getElementById("i_date_of_birth_year").addEventListener("change", checkAge)
document.getElementById("i_date_of_birth_month").addEventListener("change", checkAge)
```

```html
<input type="text" name="" id="i_date_of_birth_day">
<input type="text" name="" id="i_date_of_birth_month">
<input type="text" name="" id="i_date_of_birth_year">

<input type="radio" name="" id="radio1">
<input type="radio" name="" id="radio2">
```

Answer (score 1):

The date string you are creating (with commas) is not in the correct format. But it would be better to set the day, month, and year directly

```
  var monInput = document.querySelector("#i_date_of_birth_month").value
  var dayInput = document.querySelector("#i_date_of_birth_day").value
  var yearInput = document.querySelector("#i_date_of_birth_year").value
```

This is where your problem is I believe.

```
  var dateString = monInput + ", " + dayInput + ", " + yearInput
```

Instead, you should create a default Date(), and use setFullYear, setMonth (warning: months in javascript are 0 based) and setDate

Comment: Thank you, i really appreciate the feedback!